# Keycloak customise message if user gets locked

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect

Can someone please suggest how can we customize the message when user gets locked in keycloak using its wrapper api's or any configuration in keycloak?
I am trying to implement this using java spring boot and I am receiving error in logs as  error=user_temporarily_disabled, but how to use it so that I can customise the message for this particular use.

I tried through keycloak configuration through brute force technique but it is always returning invalid credentials

Comment: do you want change the customise message from the keyword?